# Singular hypersurface along a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset  P^n$ be a smooth curve and $X^{(1)}$ the first infinitesimal neighborhood of $X$ in $P^n$ , i.e., the closed subscheme of $P^n$ with $(I_X)^2$ as the ideal sheaf. Thus $X^{(1)}_{red} = X$. How to prove that a hypersurface $Z$ of $P^n$ is singular along $X$ if and only if it contains $X^{(1)}$?.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by singular along $X$? Do you mean $Z$ is singular at some point of $X$ or it is singular at all points of $X$? Your condition is equivalent to the latter and easy to show just using definition of smoothness.

Comment: Mean singular at all points of X.